# SOLVED: Why do the tiles display as 1 column rather than the desired grid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, java-websocket

Using Node and socket.io to make an image-key chatroom using an image keyboard of 11 x 11 image keys.

The tiles (image-key)s here are meant to display as an 11 x 11 grid.
They are instead displaying as a row.
When I paste the code into fiddle with the server.js as the js for the index page, alongside the css, it does display the image containers as 11x11, but [when using actual images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blfwc.png) they display as large.

**Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashbu/5somLdve/4/) with the index.html, style.cc, and client.js** pasted in - apologies I'm not sure how to upload it all properly.

Ignore the test array, unless that is causing the problem. Surely I have imported enough to make it display at least 1 row.

Here's the server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);

// Serve the static files from the public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

// Listen for incoming connections from clients
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user has connected');

    // Listen for incoming chat messages from clients
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        console.log(`Message: ${msg}`);
        io.emit('chat message', msg); // Broadcast the message to all connected clients
    });

    // Listen for disconnections from clients
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('A user has disconnected');
    });
});

// Start the server
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
Here is the automatic size modification that didn't work
.image-key {
    width: calc((100% - 10 * 5px) / 11);
    height: calc((100% - 10 * 5px) / 11);
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

The file structure is in the image.

....

I've tried making them 50 px, 70 px, 100 px, and using an automatic size, but to no avail.

Here is the automatic size modification that didn't work

```
.image-key {
    width: calc((100% - 10 * 5px) / 11);
    height: calc((100% - 10 * 5px) / 11);
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Solved: style.css was in wrong directory

Answer (score 0):

Style.css was in wrong directory. Placed it in "public" and all good.